# Create exe with launch4j with maven

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I want to wrap my jar with launch4j to an exe file. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.thz.cameracontrol</groupId>
<artifactId>Kamerasteuerung</artifactId>
<version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>name</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <version.maven.compiler>2.3.2</version.maven.compiler>
    <version.maven.site>3.3</version.maven.site>
    <version.sonar>4.3</version.sonar>
    <artifact.id>Kamerasteuerung</artifact.id>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <!-- profiles for repositories and distribution management -->
</profiles>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.compiler}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.maven.site}</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- LAUNCH4J -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                            <configuration>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <jar>target/Kamerasteuerung-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>target/CameraControl.exe</outfile>
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>de.thz.cameracontrol.server.Server</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <jre>
                                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                <runtimeBits>32</runtimeBits>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                                <copyright>C</copyright>
                                <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                                <internalName>AppName</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>CameraControl.exe</originalFilename>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.thz.cameracontrol.server.Server</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- LAUNCH4J ENDE -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

And this is my batch:

```
@echo off
call mvn -D skipTests clean assembly:attached
pause
```

I get a correct jar with my dependencies but i dont get an exe file. Is there something else to do? Is an descriptor.xml really necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I did not check your pom properly. As it is producing correct jar, I think it is fine.
Did you try *mvn package* ?

Comment: That was it. It solved my problem. Very stupid mistake. Thanks.