# create an executable jar including all of its dependencies in NetBeans

Tags: java, executable, netbeans-8

I have seen many methods of creating an executable jar including all of its dependencies using eclipse, MAVEN and cmd. I want to create an executable jar with its dependencies using NetBeans.

Comment: you can use **Excelsior JET**

Comment: Make a **maven** project in NetBeans too.

Answer (score 0):

there i tools available to make jars executable and my preferred one is Launch4J. you can configure Lauch4j in your maven to get the exe on build as well.
For manual configuration refer the link https://techwayz.com/convert-jar-to-exe-launch4j/

to understand maven configuration you can refer stackoverflow answer [Create exe with launch4j with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295726/create-exe-with-launch4j-with-maven)